# angularJS data not available due to async call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my controller:

```
function TestCtrl ($scope, sharedProperties, $resource){
    var userDataProfile = sharedProperties.getUserDataProfile();
    var userCreatedBoard = $resource('/boards?owner=:owner');
    userCreatedBoard.query({'owner':userDataProfile.id}, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Now problem is `sharedProperties.setUserDataProfile()` is called after calling a 3rd party service and its async. Hence, when the `TestCtrl` is bound, `userDataProfile` is effectively null. How do I handle this situation so that after the `sharedProperties.setUserDataProfile()` is called and variable has been assigned a value from 3rd party service, then only my controller should get bound?

Comment: are u using $routeprovider ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look at resolve:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr1qZ8Ik9G8

This allows you to load all your data before instantiating your controller and firing a routeChangeSuccess event.

In the [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider).

Answer (score -1):

It does not make sense to pass variables into an Angular.js controller like that, that is what the Scope variable is meant for.

Try this

```
window.activeTestCtrls = [];
window.sharedProperties = [];
function TestCtrl ($scope, $resource){
  if (window.sharedProperties) this.createUserData(window.sharedProperties) 
  window.activeTestCtrls.push[this];    
  function createUserData(sharedProperties) {
    var userDataProfile = sharedProperties.getUserDataProfile();
    var userCreatedBoard = $resource('/boards?owner=:owner');
    userCreatedBoard.query({'owner':userDataProfile.id}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});

// and when you get your sharedproperties
function gotSharedProperties(sharedProperties) {
  $.each(activeTestControllers, function(index,value) {      
     activeTestControllers[index].createUserData(sharedProperties)})
  }
}
```